# How to prove that a function has at least one real zero?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $$f(x)=5\cdot x\cdot\ln( \operatorname{tg}(x))+x-5.$$
How can one prove that it has at least one (real) zero? I have no idea how to solve equation $$f(x)=0,$$ another way I've considered would be to prove that the function is continuous in a certain interval and then prove that it has both negative and positive values in that interval (this probably won't work in this function because of $tg(x)$, it becomes obvious when seeing the graph).

Comment: Is $tg(x)$ the tangent function?

Comment: You need Bolzano’s Theorem ;)

Comment: @saulspatz yes.

Comment: @FedePoncio I was supposed to solve this problem without it (I think my teacher / assistant assumed that as we have never used it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is continuous in $(0,\frac\pi2)$. You can get negative values when $\tan x<1$, i.e. $x<\frac\pi4$. It works with $\frac\pi6$. Then close to $\frac\pi2$ you will find positive values, e.g. $x=\frac{5\pi}{12}$.

Comment: That's exactly what I've considered, but that method works only because it is possible in this problem.How would one solve a problem like this one when plugging in random values isn't possible (using a calculator or any help isn't an option)?

Comment: @JoeDough: study the curve, find continuous sections and obtain the extrema or vertical asymptotes. In the case at hand, this is quite uneasy.

Comment: I'm not able to find the extrema (there's just one), I was supposed to solve this problem without the knowledge required for solving such equations.Even if I could have found one, how would I find another value (with different sign) and prove that both of them are on a continuous segment?

Comment: @JoeDough: you were asking for the general method, don't complain to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Compute $$f(4)$$ and $$f(3.5)$$

Comment: Does your method require a calculator?Wolframalpha gives inconvenient results (f(3) is a complex number).

Comment: Ok then use $$f(3.5)$$

Comment: It's correct, but how did you find these values and calculate f(x) for each one?

Comment: You must prove that $$\ln(\tan(7/2))<0$$

Comment: since $$\tan(7/2)<1$$

Answer (score 1):

The function$$f(x)=5 x \log (\tan (x))+x-5$$ **must** have an infinite number of zero's because of the vertical asymptotes corresponding to $\tan(x)=0$ or $\tan(x)=\infty$. So, it has at least one.

For the first positive root, close to $x=0$, $\tan(x)\simeq x$ and when, $x \to 0$, $x \log(x) \to 0$ which makes $f(0)=-5$. When $x \to \frac \pi 2 -\epsilon$, $f\left(\frac \pi 2 -\epsilon \right) \to \infty$. So, you have at least a root in this range.

When $x=\frac \pi 4$, $f\left(\frac \pi 4\right)=\frac \pi 4-5 <0$ and this still reduces the range. Try with $f\left(\frac \pi 3\right)$ which is still negative.